# Paragraph Tag forces parent to take full width of flexbox

Tags: css

I am trying to create a very simple layout where a heading, paragraph and button are aligned to the center of the page horizontally and vertically. I want the `.centered-div` to take the width of the `.heading`.

Trouble is the paragraph tag seems to break the whole thing by making the `.centered-div` take the width of the `.container` instead of the width of the `.heading`.

If I remove the paragraph `.centered-div` takes it's maximum width to be the width of the `.heading`.

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.centered-div {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.heading {
  display: inline-block;
  text-align: right;
}

.description {
  display: inline-block;
  width: 50%;
}

.link-button {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered-div">
    <h1 class="heading">A Considerably Long Heading</h1>
    <p class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor...
    </p>
    <a class="button" href="/">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

In grey is the `.container` and the red outline is the `.centered-div`

[image: The output with the paragraph tag]
[image: the output without the paragraph tag]

If more information is needed please let me know.
Thanks in advance for your help.

Comment: Not sure what breaks in the snippet. It is working as expected. Want to show us the problem through a screenshot with captions?

Comment: I guess it's because the text in the example is short. If the paragraph is long it will exceed the length of the title.

Answer (score 3):

You can use the trick `width:0;min-width:100%;` with the text container which will allow it to follow the width of the header:

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.centered-div {
  display: flex;
  margin: auto;
  align-self: center;
  align-items: flex-end;
  flex-direction: column;
}

.heading {
  text-align: right;
}

.description {
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
  text-align:justify;
}

.link-button {
  width: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="centered-div">
    <h1 class="heading">A Considerably Long Heading</h1>
    <p class="description">
      Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolorLorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor Lorem ipsum dolor 
    </p>
    <a class="button" href="/">Learn More</a>
  </div>
</div>
```